# Проектирование БД sql

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Здраствуйте, у меня есть сайт объявлений по недвижимости. При добавлении клиента, можно указать несколько рубрик, которыми клиент интересуется:

1. Аренда дома
2. Аренда коммерческой недвижимости
3. Аренда комнаты

У каждого типа недвижимости есть свой набора параметров, которые вводит клиент:

- Аренда дома(площадь, количество этажей, удобства(tv,wifi).. и тд
- Аренда коммерческой недвижимости(площадь, тип, и т.д.)
- Аренда комнаты(площадь, количество комнат, удобства, и т.д)

Вот не знаю как организовать БД, чтобы хранить все данные. Пока идея сделать 
3 таблицы - object_type, attributes и attributes_value

object_type('id', 'name')
attributes('id', 'type', 'name', 'add_options', 'object_type_id')
attributes_value('id', 'attribute_id', 'value', 'client_id')

В таблице object_type, к примеру  -

```
name = 'Продам дом'
```

В таблице attributes, к примеру  -

```
name = 'Количество комнат'
type = 'text'
object_type_id = object_type.name = 'Продам дом'
```

В таблице attributes_value - id записи атрибута, и значение. 
Т.е. клиенту будет предлагать attributes.name, в зависимости от выбранного нами ранее object_type
И поле для записи - value из таблицы attributes_value .

Но такой подход мне как-то не очень нравится, возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой??
Как лучше организовать БД, и как проще будет с ней работать через PHP, использую yii2 framework.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте подход **Class Table Inheritance (Наследование с таблицами классов)**

Выделяем общую таблицу

1. **rent** - Общая таблица для объявлений

   - id - Номер объявления
   - title - Название объявления
   - description - Описание объявления
   - area - Площадь
   - type - Тип обьявления (RENT_HOUSE, RENT_COMMERCIAL, и т.д)

**Делаем таблицы с дополнительными параметрами** для каждого объявления, будем их джойнить в зависимости от поля type:

2. **rent_house** - Дополнительная таблица параметров для аренды дома

   - rent_id - Номер обьявления
   - number_floors - Кол-во этажей
   - land_area - Площадь участка
3. **rent_commercial**

   - rent_id - Номер обьявления
   - type - Тип
   - ceiling_height - высота потолка

**Выделяем общую таблицу с удобствами**, т.к. она есть в нескольких типах объявлений:

4. **rent_comfort** - Таблица удобств

   - rent_id - Номер объявления
   - comfort_name (or comfort_id) - Название типа удобства (можно использовать varchar или создать отдельную таблицу которая будет указывать на список удобств и использовать внешний ключ)

Остальные таблицы сможете спроектировать самостоятельно на основе подобной структуры. Ваш первый подход похож на EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) и его хорошо использовать на небольших объемах данных, иначе в будущем таблица с атрибутами может разрастись и это сильно ударит по производительности, возрастают затраты на реализацию проверки типа данных и их приведения, работы с ними, да и по сути данный подход называют часто выворачиванием реляционной структуры наизнанку, но никто не говорит, что их нельзя использовать, все зависит от задачи, очень удобно хранить например системные настройки.

**system_settings**

- setting VARCHAR(255)
- value VARCHAR(255)

Comment: Если Postgres то еще и проще. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html

Answer (score 1):

Можно выделить основные признаки этих сущностей в основную таблицу, думаю таких найдется не мало (например площадь и т.д.). Остальное в выделенные таблицы для каждого типа.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/114021)

Comment: @torokhkun Голосую против этой проверки. Автор указал решение проблемы (вынести в основную таблицу и в выделенные), которая помогает задающему вопрос разобраться в решении.